# Facebook api sharedposts issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When i am trying to retrieve the shared items for a specific post like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{Post-id}/sharedposts
```

i get an empty set:

```
{ data: [] }
```

I saw that there is an old issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1404733043148335/ for that but still does not seem to work. Is there any suggestion on how to get the names of people that shared a specific post?

Comment: Your app can only see posts by users that have granted your app user_posts permission.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @CBroe , i request user_posts permission but still cannot get the people that shared the specific post.

Comment: You would need user_posts from the user that shared the post.

Comment: @CBroe which is practically impossible... is there another work around for this? Because the names are viewable at the post UI in facebook..

Comment: No. And visible via FB UI and API are two different things.